# How can I show HTML Content-Type As Jpeg with a Base64 Decoded Image?

Tags: php, html, content-type

```
<?php
require 'conn.php';
if ($link) {
$EventId=$_GET['id']; 
$query="SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventId='$EventId'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
$photo=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
echo'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$photo['image'].'">';
}
else{
echo mysqli_error($link);
}
?>
```

the code above is used to read data from the database. Using an $_GET['id'] which i send from another page with the Link http://127.0.0.1/app/get_image.php?id=7. When i run this code i get the error show in the image
[image]

Comment: you cant set ImageHeader and then print HTML!! Just do print $photo['image']; or `print base64_decode($photo['image']);`

Comment: You have to choose, Content-Type between image, or HTML, there you do the two. You set the content type to image but you send html content ... `echo base64_decode($photo['image'])` will do the trick na ?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions  it brings the same error message

Comment: What does the `$photo['image']` contains (just the ~16 first bytes)

Comment: well a simple php file containing `<?php header('Content-type:image/jpeg'); readfile('image.jpeg');` works ...

Comment: @rap-2-h $photo[image ] contains base64 encoded image string like /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAiQCJAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgM....

Comment: @Bob0t elaborate more about your answer with the code in my question